# Python 3: How to extract url image?

Tags: javascript, python, regex, web-scraping

The urls I want to extract have same pattern:

```
"begin" : "url_I_want_extract"
```

They look like:

```
"begin" : "https://k2.website.com/images/0x0/0x0/0/16576946054146395951.jpeg"
"begin" : "https://k2.website.com/images/0x0/0x0/0/9460365509030976330.jpeg"
"begin" : "https://k2.website.com/images/0x0/0x0/0/9361112829030898475.jpeg"
"begin" : "https://k3.website.com/images/0x0/0x0/0/14705723619301900580.jpeg"
"begin" : "https://k3.website.com/images/8x36/922x950/0/1368601155311066426.jpeg"
```

And I used this code to extract but getting unexpected things.

```
r = re.findall('https://k(.?).website.com/images/0x0/0x0/0/(.*?).jpeg', response.text)
```

The output I got:

```
 [('2', '16576946054146395951'), ('2', '9460365509030976330'), ('2', '9361112829030898475'), ('3', '14705723619301900580')]
```

The output I want:

```
https://k2.website.com/images/0x0/0x0/0/16576946054146395951.jpeg
https://k2.website.com/images/0x0/0x0/0/9460365509030976330.jpeg
https://k2.website.com/images/0x0/0x0/0/9361112829030898475.jpeg
https://k3.website.com/images/0x0/0x0/0/14705723619301900580.jpeg
https://k3.website.com/images/8x36/922x950/0/1368601155311066426.jpeg
```

How to use regex to scrape Urls after ""begin"" word ? Thank you :)

Comment: What's wrong with that output? You make two groups - `k(.?)` and `(.*?).jpeg` - and get two results per match - `('2', 'jpg number')`. Don't group the `.?` if you don't want it in the results, or `r = [match[1] for match in r]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is to extract only the URLs after `begin :`. For this you'd want:

```
r = re.findall('"begin" : "(https://k.*?.jpeg)"', response.text)
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 2):

The parenthesis surround the capturing groups that are returned by `findall`.  Right now your capturing groups are `k(.>)` and `(.*?).jpeg`.  Remove those parenthesis and instead capture the entire url.

Also, to match both the url's with "/0x0/0x0/0/" and "/8x36/922x950/0/", replace "/0x0/0x0/0/" in the regex with "/.*/.*/.*/":

```
r = re.findall('(https://k.?.website.com/images/.*/.*/.*/.*?.jpeg)', response.text)
```

Comment: Thank you :). It worked but not still my expectation. It does not extract the last url (https://k3.website.com/images/8x36/922x950/0/1368601155311066426.jpeg)

Comment: How to use regex to scrape Urls after ""begin"" word ?

Answer (score 1):

This one may do the trick on a more general server path construction:

```
https?.*(jpeg|jpg|png|tiff|gif)
```

Start capturing the http ( with optional 's' for ssl servers ) and finish capture assuring a image file format. ( Please note that I included 5 types just as an example...)

[image: Demo]

Hope that helps !!